# Is service killed when we onbound from that?

Tags: android, android-service

in Android api guides in [managing bound services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Lifecycle):
"When a service is unbound from all clients, the Android system destroys it"
my question is: is service killed without finishing its task or after doing its task
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is service killed without finishing its task or after doing its task

The service is destroyed once the last bound connection is unbound, and if nobody has called `startService()` to send a command to the service (that itself has not been reversed with a `stopService()` or `stopSelf()` call).

If you wish to have some "task" that proceeds after all connections might be unbound, you wil need to use `startService()` somewhere, or move that task into a separate service (e.g., an `IntentService`).

Comment: let me ask my question more specifically i have an activity that monitors the download service(i'm using IntentService) and service updates progress in activity whenever it is present. activity's duty is to control the process of download(resume, pause...) and for this reason i want to keep track of download when activity is not present.(so i think moving into separate service wouldn't work)

Comment: @Sourena_: If you are using an `IntentService`, you should not be using the binding pattern IMHO. Use `startService()` to send the download request to the service. Have the service use `LocalBroadcastManager`, Square's Otto, greenrobot's EventBus, or a similar means to alert observers of progress. Requests "to control the process of download(resume, pause...)" would be done by calls to `startService()`, setting status flags that your download background thread would monitor (e.g., `AtomicBoolean`).

Comment: @Sourena_: Regardless, if you are using `IntentService`, you must have used `startService()` to start it (otherwise, that's a bug in your implementation). The service will stay running until `onHandleIntent()` is done processing the download, regardless of whether or not your bound connections are unbound.

Comment: of course i have used startService from my activity to run service so the service will stay running until onHandleIntent() done. thank you